# Python Permutation Backtracking - Why do I have to call list in this backtracking example?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, permutation, backtracking

In the code blow why do I need to call list() in the base case? If I don't call the list on current_perm, it just returns a list of empty lists.

```
        permutations = []

# returns a list of its permutation
        def permutation(nums, current_perm = []):
            if len(nums) == 0:
                # must call list on current_perm
                # not sure why
                permutations.append(list(current_perm))
            else:
                for idx, num in enumerate(nums):
                    current_perm.append(num)
                    # pass nums as nums without the current number
                    permutation(nums[:idx]+nums[idx+1:], current_perm)
                    # backtrack
                    current_perm.pop()
```

Comment: `list(current_perm)` creates a new list and copies the contents of `current_perm` into that list.

Comment: It's making a copy of `current_perms`. Otherwise all your `permutations` would be references to the same list, which you modify in place.

Comment: It would be clearer if they wrote `permutations.append(current_perms.copy())`